# Neo4J Docker Container Constantly Restarts

Tags: neo4j

Presently running docker desktop on windows. Using a Neo4j 4.0.4 or 4.0.7. I have recently starting seeing this constantly restart every so many seconds.

When looking at the logs in the docker console for the container.

```
Starting Neo4j.

2022-04-28 17:36:45.021+0000 INFO  Note that since you did not explicitly set the port in dbms.connector.bolt.advertised_address Neo4j automatically set it to 7687 to match dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address. This behavior may change in the future and we recommend you to explicitly set it.

2022-04-28 17:36:45.028+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.0.4 ========

2022-04-28 17:36:45.031+0000 INFO  Starting...

2022-04-28 17:36:52.667+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabaseService@44fff386' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Mismatching store id. Store StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1651155662620, randomId=155159839854920640, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1651155662620, upgradeTxId=1}. Transaction log StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1650887045799, randomId=2291666590955424440, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1650887045799, upgradeTxId=1}". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabaseService@44fff386' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Mismatching store id. Store StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1651155662620, randomId=155159839854920640, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1651155662620, upgradeTxId=1}. Transaction log StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1650887045799, randomId=2291666590955424440, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1650887045799, upgradeTxId=1}".

org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabaseService@44fff386' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Mismatching store id. Store StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1651155662620, randomId=155159839854920640, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1651155662620, upgradeTxId=1}. Transaction log StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1650887045799, randomId=2291666590955424440, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1650887045799, upgradeTxId=1}".

at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:45)

at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:164)

at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:114)

at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:89)

at com.neo4j.server.enterprise.EnterpriseEntryPoint.main(EnterpriseEntryPoint.java:25)

Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabaseService@44fff386' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Mismatching store id. Store StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1651155662620, randomId=155159839854920640, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1651155662620, upgradeTxId=1}. Transaction log StoreId: StoreId{creationTime=1650887045799, randomId=2291666590955424440, storeVersion=3471765337752883975, upgradeTime=1650887045799, upgradeTxId=1}".

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:465)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)

at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:157)

... 3 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting database server at /data/databases

at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:167)

at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:145)

at com.neo4j.server.database.EnterpriseGraphFactory.newDatabaseManagementService(EnterpriseGraphFactory.java:38)

at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabaseService.start(LifecycleManagingDatabaseService.java:88)

at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
```

Wondering what I need to be considering looking at to resolve, or maybe there is a known solution?

Cheers